# Web API request to get a response from another local service

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, windows-services, azure-webjobs

I am currently running a VM on Azure.  On the VM I have a Windows Service running that processes incoming files saved by a Web API endpoint running in an IIS application.  The result of the API is a URL to a results .zip file after the service has processed the incoming file.

I'm not currently handling messaging between the service and the API.  Instead, I set the name of the file saved on the server, then intrinsically know the name of the results file.

The windows service could run as an Azure web job or something else, but I'm trying to determine the best way to "process" the file in a synchronous way so the Web API endpoint could actually return the results XML instead of simply a URL to the output.

I don't want to put the file processing logic in the web API application, so what are my options?

Answer (score 0):

Can you expose a Web API on the Azure VM?

1. IIS Web API makes a call to Azure Web API with the file
2. Azure Web API does processing work (or delegates the work) and puts the file in the response
3. ISS Web API forwards the response back to the original caller

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, your API could process incoming files and saved to your Azure VM. I would recommend you to save the files to [attached disk](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-attach-disk-portal/) or uploading to Azure storage directory.

> "process" the file in a synchronous way

In general, we usually process in a asynchronous way in Web API. If you don't want to use Web API to process the file, please consider use background task to do this. such as [write console application then use Windows Scheduler](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/manas1/console-application-using-windows-scheduler/) to process the file. In this way you can use synchronous way to process the file.